# check current active network manager

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking

this morning my Ubuntu didn't connected automatically to my wifi network. In my network-manager conf for my network i saw that either the name of my wifi module or the line in the conf where it specifies the module, changed. I changed the line in the config to the current name of my wifi-module and it worked fine.

To ensure i can troubleshoot better i installed dhcpcd5 but uninstalled in the next minute, because it did work before (Don't ask why I know that this is a bad idea). After the next reboot my network connected automatically, but somehow i have no /etc/network-manager dir anymore and i have to reconnect to my vpn every every hour again. This is the output of `sudo apt list | grep network-manager` because i am not 100% sure if it's still right installed.

```
budgie-network-manager-applet/impish 1.3.0-0ubuntu1 amd64
network-manager-config-connectivity-debian/impish,impish 1.32.12-0ubuntu1 all
network-manager-config-connectivity-ubuntu/impish,impish,now 1.32.12-0ubuntu1 all [installed]
network-manager-dev/impish,impish 1.32.12-0ubuntu1 all
network-manager-fortisslvpn-gnome/impish 1.2.10-0ubuntu2 amd64
network-manager-fortisslvpn/impish 1.2.10-0ubuntu2 amd64
network-manager-gnome/impish,now 1.24.0-1ubuntu1 amd64 [residual-config]
network-manager-iodine-gnome/impish 1.2.0-3ubuntu1 amd64
network-manager-iodine/impish 1.2.0-3ubuntu1 amd64
network-manager-l2tp-gnome/impish 1.2.18-1build1 amd64
network-manager-l2tp/impish 1.2.18-1build1 amd64
network-manager-openconnect-gnome/impish 1.2.6-1 amd64
network-manager-openconnect/impish 1.2.6-1 amd64
network-manager-openvpn-gnome/impish,now 1.8.14-1 amd64 [installed]
network-manager-openvpn/impish,now 1.8.14-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
network-manager-pptp-gnome/impish,now 1.2.8-3build1 amd64 [installed]
network-manager-pptp/impish,now 1.2.8-3build1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
network-manager-ssh-gnome/impish 1.2.11-1 amd64
network-manager-ssh/impish 1.2.11-1 amd64
network-manager-strongswan/impish 1.5.2-1 amd64
network-manager-vpnc-gnome/impish 1.2.6-3 amd64
network-manager-vpnc/impish 1.2.6-3 amd64
network-manager/impish,now 1.32.12-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
```

How did this happen? What is currently managing my Network?

I am afraid that after the next reboot my Network won't connect automatically and i cannot troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

'apt list' only displays packages installed. It has nothing to do with your current active network connection.

The subdirectory is actually called

```
/etc/NetworkManager
```

the configured connections are in files in the subdirectory

```
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections
```

Do not manipulate these files by hand (editor) unless you know what you are doing.
The way to check your (active) network connections when NetworkManager is responsible, is with the command

```
nmcli connection
```

To (de)activate one, use

```
nmcli connection up ConnectionName
```

or

```
nmcli connection down ConnectionName
```

It's possible you need to prefix these nmcli commands with 'sudo '.
Good luck.

Comment: But where is my NM conf that was in my home dir? And isn't nmcli a networkManager tool? I wan't to check which network tool is managing my Network. Or is every NM accessing theses configs to connect to known networks?

Comment: 'nmcli connection' shows all your configured network connections. Active or not. There is no such thing as an networkmanager systemconnection in your home directory, nor a 'network tool managing your network'. There is a _single_ process called 'NetworkManger', of which you can check the state with 'sudo systemctl status NetworkManager.service'. The program nmcli is a client that is able to influence NetworkManager's state. The commands 'man NetworkManager' and 'man nmcli' tell you more.

Comment: So why using tools like dhcpcd5 then?

Comment: Because NetworkManager is a generic tool, trying to do everything and fails. Specific tools for specific problems dropping the everything approach will always be needed.